# How to use Unicode characters in Outlook mail with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to write "Değerli Adayımız". It turns into "DeÞerli Adayýmýz" in Outlook.

I am using the code below. I deleted some code because of security.

```
Sub mailgonder()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set Signature = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\*.htm", 1)

    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "*.COM"
        .To = Cells(ki, 5)
        .CC = "*.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Deneme"
        .HTMLBody = "Değerli Adayımız" & Cells(ki, 2) & Signature.readall
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing: Set OutApp = Nothing:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add inside the with cluster

```
  With OutMail
    .HTMLBody.Charset = "UTF-8"
    ...
    ...
    .... 
 End With
```

Or whatever country code you need.